# How to create histogram and feature vector of gradient local ternary pattern of an image divided into cell

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am doing our project (facial expression recognition using gradient local ternary pattern) in Matlab. In this project, we have an image on which we apply Sobel operator find positive an negative gradient, and then we combine these gradients. After that, we can apply threshold with some value (e.g. t=80) with central then find a positive and negative code for using gradient local ternary pattern. After that finding positive and negative image by applying the code, we can divide these image into the blocks using `mat2cell` to create a histogram of these blocks of the positive and negative image.

```
% this an ltp lower(pattern for local terernary pattern for ngptl
imshow(ltp_lower),title('Pgptl')
subplot(3,3,6);
imshow(ltp_upper),title('Ngptl')
figure('Name','Ngptl');
ltp_lower1 = zeros(81,64);%zero padding to increase column
ltp_lower1(1:81,1:61)= ltp_lower; 

% create a blocks for ltp_lower1 using mat2cell
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(ltp_lower1)
blockSizeR = 9; %define the block size of row
blockSizeC = 8;% define the block size of column
wholeBlockRows = rows / blockSizeR; % the number of total block sin a image of an row
blockVectorR = [blockSizeR * ones(1, wholeBlockRows)];
wholeBlockCols = columns / blockSizeC;% the number of total block sin a image of an column
blockVectorC = [blockSizeC * ones(1, wholeBlockCols)];
ca = mat2cell(ltp_lower1, blockVectorR, blockVectorC);
plotIndex = 1;
numPlotsR = size(ca, 1);
numPlotsC = size(ca, 2);

% show the blocks of an  ltp_lower1
for r = 1 : numPlotsR
    for c = 1 : numPlotsC
        fprintf('plotindex = %d,   c=%d, r=%d\n', plotIndex, c, r);
        subplot(numPlotsR, numPlotsC, plotIndex);
        rgbBlock = ca{r,c};
        imshow(rgbBlock); 
        size(rgbBlock);
        plotIndex = plotIndex + 1;
    end
end
```

This is my code and I have a problem to create a histogram of all the cells but in my code, we show blocks by regBlock but regBlock have only last cell value. Here my problem is what input the histograms are given?

Comment: In all the code you posted you never call [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html?s_tid=doc_ta), Have you tried that? On what input? What were the results? Why they are not what you looking for? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54250266/edit) your question to include this details